# Manhwa protagonist that has a maxed-out thrust skill

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhwa where there's a guy that only uses 'thrust' and is the last guy in the tower.

He also fought the tower administrator at the top of the tower.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Tower of God...

Comment: As per the [tour], if someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: um I havent read the whole thing but could it be my daughter is the final boss?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like ***[The World After the Fall](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=195824)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Faced with imminent defeat and certain death, would you choose to run – or continue to fight for a doomed world? When mysterious towers appear across the world, summoning monsters that prey on mankind, this is the choice presented to the Tower Walkers – adventurers with special powers to fight the monsters. On the brink of death, they can choose to use a “regression stone” to return to the past for a second chance, though this decision places them in a separate timeline forever. Stubborn Tower Walker Jaehwan rejects this choice, choosing to fight for the original timeline, and learning shocking secrets about the Tower along the way.

At the beginning of chapter 1, mysterious towers start emerging from the ground in cities around the world, including Seoul in South Korea. Various people then receive invitations to become 'Tower Walkers' (i.e. dungeoneers) and 'save the world', via a video game-like interface that appears in front of them.

A young man named 'Jaehwan' is one the people who accepts this invitation, and enters the tower in Seoul as part of a large group. By the time he reaches the penultimate floor of the tower near the end of chapter 2 though, everyone else in his group has either died, or been too severely injured to continue.

In chapter 4, Jaehwan notes that he started clearing the tower later than other Walkers, and that as a result, he missed out on the opportunity to gain hidden skills and classes. He therefore gave up on developing other skills, and devoted himself solely to the art of stabbing, using his sword.

He focused on stabbing so much that his comrades started to call him 'the embodiment of stabbing', and his stabs became increasingly rapid, accurate, and powerful, to the point of having attack power on the same level as a hidden skill. But as it wasn't classed as a skill, it didn't cost spiritual power, so he could spam the attack like crazy without getting tired.

In chapter 5, he finally reaches the 'control room' at the top of the tower, where he meets the owner of the tower, Beastrein, a humanoid demon in a business suit. They talk for a while, but eventually get to fighting. During the fight, in chapter 7, Jaehwan notes that his skills are all maxed out.

[image] [image]